# Number of binary strings containing at least n 1's

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have 53 binary digits and I need to calculate how many combinations of 1's and 0's can be generated where there are at least 40 1's in the combination.

How can this be calculated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each choice counted goes with a subset of 53 things having $k$ elements, where $40 \le k \le 53.$ So the total is obtained by summing $C(53,k)$ for $k$ from $40$ to $53.$ Here $C(n,r)$ is the binomial coefficient, also written $\binom{n}{r}.$

Note: It's a big number: $1,209,397,179,048.$ (No, didn't do that by hand!) Also another way is to count where the $0$'s go, so sum $C(53,j)$ for $j$ from $0$ to $13.$

Comment: You... beat me to the question...

Comment: @Bradman175 Oh well, that's happened to me many times. It may be the question downvotes are because OP showed no attempt to solve it.

Comment: C(40, 53) + C(41, 53) + C(42, 53) + ... + C(53, 53)?

Comment: @Bradman Usually in binomial coefficients the larger number goes first.

Comment: Alternative notations include C(n, k), nCk, nCk, Ckn, Cnk, Well idk how to write it using computer text. I know how to write it using paper.

Comment: Thanks @coffeemath.  As for showing no attempt, I really didn't even know where to start!

Comment: @Lucas So do you now get the idea? For example for strings of length 5 with two 1's the string 01001 would go with the subset $\{2,5\}$ of the first 5 positive integers.

Comment: @coffemath yes, thank you